# completely reinstall ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

I have a ubuntu server I've been playing with for some time. I would like to reset ubuntu to it's original state and uninstall everything I've added. Could anyone tell me if this is possible to do from the terminal. I do not have physical access to the server.

Thanks,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu installation and not programming as defined in the [help] guidelines. It is better suited for [ubuntu.se] or [sf] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some options to follow in order to return the machine to its initial state but that's a pain, and there is no guarantee that every configuration you made will get back to its default setting. If you want to learn more here are some links to AskUbuntu:

- [How to uninstall all but the default Ubuntu packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39658/how-to-uninstall-all-but-the-default-ubuntu-packages)
- [Where can    I find a complete list of packages that I have
  installed after    initial installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39633/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-packages-that-i-have-installed-after-initial/39638#39638)
- [Can I reset everything to its factory    default settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101534/can-i-reset-everything-to-its-factory-default-settings)

Imho the best way to go is by contacting whoever has physical access to your server and ask them to re-install Ubuntu from scratch.

Comment: thanks will check out the links!